# AEM not able to use Content Fragment variations in a Fragment reference data types

Tags: aem, aem-6

I don't see an option to select a Content fragment variation to be used with fragment reference data type. Wondering if I'm missing something or if any other data type that can use Content fragment variations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select a specific variation directly in the picker.  The intent of the CF is supposed to be more holistic to include all variations, then allow the consumer to determine what variation fits the need.
If you do need a specific variation, and you have them consistently named,  you could add a field to name which variation should be included.  Then the query could filter based on that provided value so that it can inform the consumer which of the _variations to use.